# How to post images (as photos) to Facebook using FB.ui feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I post images using FB.ui feed it works fine but the images are links son when you click on them you cannot see a bigger version of the image.

I read that you can use:
FB.api('/me/photos?access_token=’… 
But I need the dialog so the user can see the photo and add a message in FB “environment or context”.

This should be simple, no?

This is my current code:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: url_base,
    picture: up_img_final_url,
    name: FBname,
    caption: FBcap,
    description: FBdesc, 
};
FB.ui(obj, function(response){
    if(response)console.log('Post');
    else console.log('Cancel');
});
```